# OpenLDAP memberOf overlay - changing memberOf attribute name

Tags: openldap

I set up the memberOf overlay for OpenLDAP - how do I change the memberOf attribute name?

I want to change it to "isMemberOf".

I tried changing this attribute in the configuration

```
olcMemberOfMemberOfAD: isMemberOf
```

but ldapadd failed:

```
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: unable to find memberof attribute="isMemberOf":
attribute type undefined (17)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an attribute that actually exists in the schema.

Comment: Where is memberOf actually defined in the LDAP schema?   I don't see it in any of the files under /etc/ldap/ - if it were, I could change it?  I thought the whole point is memberOf isn't a real schema attribute, which is why it has to be explicitly requested (operational attribute).  

Since the memberOf overlay attribute is supposed to be configurable,  what else needs to be changed to use that olcMemberOfMemberOfAD option?

Comment: @wrschneider99 It appears when I browse my schema. Don't know where it came from. Why do you think you need to change it?

Comment: compatibility with code that is running on Sun Java Directory Server and expects `isMemberOf`